# Silverlight 4 - Tournament style view (knockout, tree)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, uicontrol

I'm trying to create a view in Silverlight that can display rounds in a tournament. At the moment I have a set of grid views side by side and each one shows all the people still in that round of the knockout.

What I am trying to achieve is a view that shows clearly who played who and when their next games. Something similar to the below. I'm just wanting some pointers in the direction of what control I could manipulate enough to achieve this as I am very much new to Silverlight.

[image: Knockout Tournament]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for components you can tweak to work this way, I would strongly recommend investigating some of the third-party components designed for creating diagrams and/or org charts.  Some cost money, but in my experience, the cost of a third-party control is less than the cost of my time to reproduce it myself.  Here are some links to investigate:

Free: (Most of these are vertical, but you could tweak them to meet your horizontal layout):
    http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Org_Chart_Generator.aspx
    http://omourad.blogspot.com/2009/08/silverlight-organization-chart.html
    http://www.sharpdevel.com/2009/12/organization-chart-free-control-in.html

Money:
    http://nwoods.com/components/silverlight-wpf/goxam-overview.htm (<-- my personal preference)
    http://www.mindfusion.eu/diagramlite.html
    http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/silverlight/diagram

Good luck!